# Can't update to Windows 8 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-8-upgrade, visual-artifacts

I was trying to update Windows 7 to Windows 8 from original Microsoft DVD, but it always stops at installing drivers. I removed all the uncompatible drivers (like TP-Link's antenna driver). My BIOS is updated and I have no incompatible apps. Each time, after upgrading, I have weird glitched BSOD, so I can't tell you the error message. Is there any way to upgrade my PC to Windows 8? I don't want to do a clean install.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BSOD is usually the result of a driver error or incompatible drivers. Make sure  you are using the right Windows DVD for your CPU architecture. If your CPU is a 32-bit or 64-bit, be sure to use the corresponding Windows DVD.

Comment: I was using right DVD, 64-bit

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the glitched BSOD? What exactly appears on your screen? If you can upload a picture that would be great.

Comment: http://imgur.com/pnk5Uib

Comment: Ah, definitely an incompatible video driver. It's possible the driver on that install DVD is incompatible with the video card on your computer. I would suggest testing that Win 8 install DVD on another computer to be absolutely sure it is functional before proceeding.
Replacing a video card is a last resort as it costs both time and money.

Comment: Sure it's a video driver! I'm so stupid haha :P
I have Radeon card and as you can see - http://support.amd.com/en-us/download - if I install version for Windows 7 it won't be compatible with Windows 8. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help